# Allow the user to press enter, but do not move down the row in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, enter

I have a very patchy complicated code as I am a learning student.

When I press enter on the keyboard, an SQL command is executed FOR THE NEXT LINE of the datagrid rather than the previous line in which I just changed. I understand this may just be order; but I have checked all of this and it still wants to move down to the next line before the command is executed. I cannot provide code as such as it is for an assignment and 'Turnitin' will retrieve the online data for this...

So, how do I keep enter enabled, but not allow it to move down to the next line in the data grid?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: A what? I'm confused.

Comment: I edited your question an hour ago and I removed the `C# WPF` part from the title. You don't have to include information about language used in a title, just use appropriate tags (c#, wpf, datagrid, enter)

Comment: Do you really want to disable the movement downwards? Or would just ensuring that the SQL command is run on the previous line be sufficient? What event have you subscribed to to invoke the SQL command?